# Unable to connect to Postgres database in C# code through XPO

Tags: c#, postgresql, devexpress

```
public void Start()
{
    try
    {
        // Create thread-safe- load and build the domain!
        _log.Info("Attempting to validate and build/load domain");
        var connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ConnectionString;
        var dataStore = XpoDefault.GetConnectionProvider(connStr, AutoCreateOption.None);

        using (var dataLayer = new SimpleDataLayer(dataStore))
        {
            using (var session = new Session(dataLayer))
            {
                XpoDefault.DataLayer = new ThreadSafeDataLayer(session.Dictionary, dataStore);
            }
        }

        XpoDefault.Session = null;

        _log.Info("Successfully loaded and validated domain");
    }
}
```

This is the code I have written in C# to connect to Postgresql.

The line at which the code is breaking is

```
var dataStore = XpoDefault.GetConnectionProvider(connStr, AutoCreateOption.None);
```

I am getting this error:

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
>
> A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately XXXXXXXXXX:5432

Previously the same project is running fine but suddenly I am seeing this error. I have DevExpress 17.2 in my system. Can anyone please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is silly...but it solved my issue.  :(

Tools --> Options  --> Debugging  --> General -->  Enable Just My Code

I checked this flag in Visual Studio 2017 and the issue was resolved.

Comment: in my case Enable Just My Code was already checked. Unchecking it resolved the issue. Don't ask an for explanation cause I don't have one :D